# How do I get the `for` loop to not stop after an os command?

Tags: python, for-loop, cmd, operating-system, taskkill

I automate a process with *Task Schedule*r that occasionally leaves EXCEL.EXE processes hung in the background and these interfere with future processes. I found a way to list these to a file with a `.bat` code. The scheduled task starts code that calls a `.vbs` file that executes a macro in `Excel`. So *Task Scheduler* can't be set up to cancel the process (PID) if it hangs.

```
tasklist /V /FO csv /FI "IMAGENAME eq EXCEL.EXE" > C:\[path]\Exceltasks.csv
```

creates...(example)

```
"Image Name","PID","Session Name","Session#","Mem Usage","Status","User Name","CPU Time","Window Title"
"EXCEL.EXE","62020","Console","1","622,528 K","Running","[network]\[user]","0:03:31","Work Record.xlsx - Excel"
"EXCEL.EXE","47536","Console","1","78,760 K","Running","[network]\[user]","0:00:00","N/A"
"EXCEL.EXE","61472","Console","1","620,752 K","Running","[network]\[user]","0:03:38","N/A"
"EXCEL.EXE","54156","Console","1","358,648 K","Not Responding","[network]\[user]","0:00:20","HardwareMonitorWindow"
"EXCEL.EXE","54604","Console","1","77,180 K","Running","[network]\[user]","0:00:00","N/A"
"EXCEL.EXE","45948","Console","1","368,400 K","Running","[network]\[user]","0:00:24","Publishing..."
```

Then I have this python script that will run through that file and uses `taskkill` to clear them out.

```
import csv
import os
FindValue = "EXCEL.EXE"
Substring = "- Excel"

with open("C:/[path]/Exceltasks.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if (row[0]=="INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria."):
            print ("No " + FindValue + " processes running")
            break
        else:
            print ("Check PID" + row[1])
            if(row[0]==FindValue):
                if(row[8].find("- Excel")!=-1):
                    print("Don't kill task " + row[1])
                else:
                    Killstring = "taskkill /F /PID " + row[1]
                    print Killstring
                    os.system('cmd /k '+ Killstring)
```

The first `if` will `break` out if there are no EXCEL.EXE processes.
The second `if` works, but only on the first of what is often 3+ EXEL.EXE processes.

**How do I get the `for` loop to not stop after the first `os` `taskkill` command?**

Comment: Don't use `os.system` at all. Use `subprocess`, which lets you create a subprocess that *doesn't* block your script, but runs in the background. Also, looking at your code, look in the `os` module for a function that can do what you need without leaving Python at all.

Comment: Off-topic: You're not skipping the header row of the CSV file — you need to call `next(reader)` once before entering the `for` loop.

Comment: Are you sure, you want `cmd /k` and not `cmd /c`? See `cmd /?` for how they differ.

Comment: Instead of running `TaskList` to output it results to a text file, then parsing it with a python script, what is wrong with just using `TaskKill` to close all `not responding` instances of `excel.exe`? e.g. `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /F /Fi "Status eq Not Responding" /Im EXCEL.EXE 1>NUL 2>&1`.